# Match array values against text

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you perform a preg_match where the pattern is an array, in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683702/how-do-you-perform-a-preg-match-where-the-pattern-is-an-array-in-php)

How can I match values from an array against a string?

I use a an array to fix typos in a text. I want to recycle this array for matching its values.

```
$fruitNameFixes = array(
        '/bann?ann?a/i' => 'banana',        
        '/app?e?le?/i' => 'apple',
    );

$str = "I like bananas and oranges!";

if( preg_match('/(banana|apple)/i', $str) ) { //add $fruitNameFixes values
    echo "He likes fruits from the fruitNameFixes array";
} else {
    echo "Nope, he doesn't like fruits from the fruitNameFixes array";
}
```

Test: http://codepad.viper-7.com/N92WVb

Comment: I want to match all fruits in the array ("banana" and "apple") against the string.

Comment: `implode('|', $fruitNameFixes)` works: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Xk1h1t - but does it only use the values or also the keys for the match?

Comment: Print `$fruitNameFixes_flattened` and see for yourself! And/or read [the documentation for `implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). It's all there. Some research effort required...

Comment: Cheers, you're right of course.